# Bootstrap backdrop covers modal after dropping element on Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

**Way to reproduce the issue:**
When I drag my draggable element (from outside of the Fullcalendar) onto Fullcalendar and then initiate the Bootstrap modal, the modal-backdrop **is covering the modal**. In opposite when I'm not dropping the droppable element onto the calendar the modal is visible and the modal-backdrop **is not covering the modal**.

**Additional information:**
When I'm dragging and dropping elements inside the Fullcalendar the Bootstrap modal works well.

**Thing I'm sure of:**

1. The Bootstrap modal is placed between `<body></body>` tags.

**Fullcalendar initialization:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
locale:'pl',
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
views: {
    month: { 
        editable: false,
        droppable: false,
    }
},
slotDuration: '00:15:00',
droppable: true,
defaultDate: date,
defaultView: viewName,
editable: true,
timeFormat:'H(:mm)',
minTime: "07:00:00",
maxTime: "18:00:00",
allDaySlot: false,
events: eventsArray,
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
    element.find(".fc-event-time").remove();
    element.find(".fc-time").remove();
    var new_description =   
            moment(event.start).format("HH:mm") + '-'
            + moment(event.end).format("HH:mm")
    ;
    element.append(new_description);
},
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

    var date = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    for(var i in holidays) {
        if(date === holidays[i].date) {
            cell.css("background-color", "#FFCBCB");
        }
    }   

},

});
```

**Modal initialization:**

```
var modal = $('#addElementModal');
modal.modal();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found solution for this case:**

I've added to the `<div class="modal">...modalcontent...</div>` the following attributes:

`data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"`

Which is simply removing the modal backdrop and add it's own backdrop.